# Dynamic dropdown returns #REF in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a dynamic dropdown that returns a list of **Job Orders Number** that have not been completed using a =filter() formula but when using Data Validation to reference this list, it returns a #REF! as seen in the image.

[image: #REF Error from Data Validation]

I have put a sample here. Where the dropdown and list of reference is found in the tab "Work Order" and the list of reference is based on the uncompleted orders found in "Order Request".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ywy9jODh82dSyyHyRMXwhcCLmmSEbnr5rWHoMC2bkJ0/edit#gid=1852020502

[image: View in Google Sheets]

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rubén thanks for sharing. Added the sample in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason you should have a `#REF!` error in that range other than if the original range was deleted or drastically altered. Even without having a range to pull, if it is pointing at a range where there will eventually be data it should work fine.

For example if you have no data in Column A:A but eventually it will hold Job Order Numbers, and you insert a FILTER formula in B that retrieves the list you want. There should be no reason your Data Validation range cannot be `=$B:$B` and it will dynamically update as Job Order Numbers are inserted and the filters begins populating the range for the drop down.

**UPDATE:**

Unless you may have a header in cell D1 why not just use `=$D:$D`?

It appears if you specify `=D2:D` like I assume you were then there is a reference error. To be honest I am not sure why that is, I cannot duplicate it under any circumstances outside of your sheet. Even when I duplicate the rabbit hole of formula's I see you're using (obtaining the RPG # via a formula, obtaining the # via  reference to a hidden sheet which is also a formula to generate each number, etc...). I essentially duplicated your required cells in my own sheet and did not have an issue.

Your options would be to hardcode the range with an ending such as `=D2:D1000` or the one I posted.

[image]

Comment: I agree and its a first for me as well. I have added a sample in the post.

Comment: Curious issue here. Apologies for not being able to conclude why `$D$2:$D` will return a `#REF!`, but I did post alternatives.

Comment: Hey hardcoded it like u said using D2:D1000. Now it works. Thanks :)